# Are sign in forms better in the left, right, or center? and why?

Tags: usability

I'm seeing a few sites with a sign in form on the far left with a billboard of info on the right (Salesforce, Mailchimp for example). Others like facebook have the sign in on the right. Most are centered. Is there any data on what performs the best?

Comment: could attach some screenshots of those signs.